# Is there a reason why Bootstrap 3 has horizontal padding in columns but not vertical?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-frameworks

I'm standing at a precipice about to make an important decision that will affect our long term development regarding Bootstrap and I want to be sure I have a good understanding of the reasoning behind their use of **Column Padding**.

We run a multi-tenant cms system that offers bootstrap as one of the available frameworks from which to build a site, and then our system adds layers of functionality on top of it, so any decision we make affects *all tenants*.

One of the basic features is when working with a Bootstrap Columns (i.e. `col-lg-6`), or what we would call a `Section`, a user can choose to have the content inside *Bleed* to the edge, or be surrounded by padding.

In bootstrap, columns use `padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;` for the horizontal, but `padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0;` for the vertical.

In our system, we would use `padding:15px;` all the way around, because users can also set a column/section background colour and/or image, and the logic is that you would want to see colour/image around all sides when not using `bleed` and vice versa.

I understand that the horizontal margins in bootstrap overlap as a function of the grid system, but padding is cumulative between columns. So my question is: **is there a reason why vertical padding is *not* also set explicitly? What are the potential repercussions of forcing this on our clients?**

**N.B.** Anything can be overridden via a Custom CSS editor, similar to the one in Wordpress, although this capability would obviously be essentially reserved for those "in the know" and not something I would expect a regular user to utilize.

---

EDIT:  The following is a test helper we've created to remove margins from the top of header tags which are the first child of one of our sections (specifics removed for clarity).

```
section h1:first-child, section h2:first-child, section h3:first-child,
section h4:first-child, section h5:first-child, section h6:first-child 
{ margin-top: 0 !important; }
```

This can also be done for last items as well to remove bottom margins/padding.

**If we expand this to cover elements noted below (i.e. forms, p, h1-6, etc.) so the normal spacing persists, would this complicate things further or be adequate to preserve Bootstraps intent while allowing our own features to work?**

Comment: That would cause some issues if the last item is a button and you remove the padding. Instead, I would (these days anyway) keep all the same and make sure that whatever someone puts in the column, whether image or whatever, has the same rhythm. So all images are forced inside a figure, which is appropriate and that figure has the same margin top as the h1-h6.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer Very good point, although even if we remove the margin from a button that happens to be last, it would still have the 15px padding below it provided by the column (with our outlined change of course).  I may have to play a bit with our mods considering an H1 has 20px top and the column would only provide 15px, but there aren't going to be a ton of elements that we need to adjust this way.  Really appreciate your input btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because inside those columns with the default gutter of 30px between columns there's generally forms, ul, ol, p, h1-h6, and other content that have bottom margins, so when it stacks there's vertical spacing, if you were to add bottom or top padding on the column  would be quite odd looking when stacked, two paragraphs inside two 50% (col-*-6) columns would have additional padding between the first and second. And nesting columns would be odd and have even more spacing issues. The only time when the vertical stacking wouldn't have space is if you were to stick images in them, but then you can add a custom class to the image to get some bottom margin on the un-floated version.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in.  I think I've seen you're answers with regard to vertical spacing in Bootstrap before, relating to form elements for instance since bootstrap lacks any vertical spacing helpers (correct me if I'm wrong).  If I'm remembering correctly, with the aid of helpers you set some slightly altered automatic spacing for elements that lack it.  I've created a simple one for our own sake which removes the 20px top margin that H1 tags get from bootstrap when they're the first element of one of our sections.  I imagine that I can do the same for the other elements you mentioned?!?!

Comment: .form-group stacks the forms with vertical spacing, the only trouble is nesting columns inside those groups. For normal forms, it doesn't come up. See BEFORE:
http://jsbin.com/xigere/1/edit

AFTER:
http://jsbin.com/vihaj/1/edit

Comment: FYI, I've just updated the question with the CSS I mentioned and what my potential solution might be. I'll take a look at your examples that just showed up too, thanks!

Comment: For normal columns, with text in both/all columns, the elements line up, but if you put an image inside one and text in the other, the top margin on the text column doesn't line up, so I either remove the top margin on just that situation or restructure

Comment: Not in our case, the first P tag would have it's top spacing removed, and the first image would have none, so they would align.  As for nested elements, I've used high selectivity so that only the first tier would be affected by the change, nested elements would continue to enjoy the default Bootstrap spacing.

Comment: Very much appreciate all your help, you raised some important caveats and our solution will be all the better for it!  Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, it's a deisgn thing. They want you to be able to vertically stack rows without any extra padding. I would design it the same way. If someone wanted to add padding, you could attach an ID on a specific row, and add padding to it. or if ou want to targer all rows, simply add that CSS on rows