# Twitter Bootstrap users - How do you handle miscellaneous vertical positioning/spacing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap with SASS. I'm using the former mainly for its grid and am trying hard to avoid adding inline-style-like attributes to rows as a means of controlling vertical spacing, as this . . .

```
.margin-top-15 {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

. . . essentially amounts to this . . .

```
<div style="margin-top: 15px;"></div>
```

Not good. Have any of you come up with a system for handling vertical positioning/spacing  that does not consist of anything resembling the above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - add top space between rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085723/twitter-bootstrap-add-top-space-between-rows)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924024/is-there-a-reason-why-bootstrap-3-has-horizontal-padding-in-columns-but-not-vert/24940928#24940928

Answer (score 1):

If the children inside the `.col-*-*` inside the `.row` has a p, h1-h6, ul, ol, form around them then you don't need anything:

https://jsbin.com/bojeje/1/edit

Bootstrap's CSS has a top and bottom margin on p, h1-h6, form, ul, ol, table (I think), .panel, and .well. The last two may just be bottom margins, you should look at the unpacked CSS to know what you're working with.

[image]

If that's not the situation, you can make a max-width (so you don't screw with the larger viewport styles and have to undo it).

```
@media (max-width:767px) {

    .row {margin-top:5%;}

}
```

Using percentages or ems even with a nested .row situation looks pretty good.